# How to stream HD video from ffmpeg using php?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I using FFmpeg to stream video HD on facebook but I have a problem. When I execute the command

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i "/var/www/1.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 500k -bufsize 2500k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 198k -ar 44100 -f flv "......."
```

in SSH, I see Video HD but when I use command through `shell_exec()` or `exec()`, I only see video in 360p or 240p.

Comment: Show the ffmpeg log.